# Phase Coefficient versus frequency plot

Tags: transmission-line, matlab, propagation

I have been asked to confirm that the propagation characteristics of a transmission line, with the given parameters

R= 2.2 Ohm, L = 105nH, C = 69pF, G = 14 nS.

Along with these two equations,

[image]

I have been able to confirm all except the phase coefficient (Beta) against frequency. The given characteristic plot being:

[image]

However when running my MATLAB Code:

```
% Constants
R = [2.2];         % ohm m^-1    
L = [105]*1e-9;        % H m^-1
C = [69]*1e-12;         % F m^-1
G = [14]*1e-9;         % S m^-1

% Frequency range
f = logspace(0,30);     % Hz 
w=(2*pi*f); %Freq in rad/sec
y=sqrt(R+(1i.*w.*L)).*(G+(1i.*w.*C));
alpha = real(y);
beta = imag(y);

% Characteristic impedance
Zo = sqrt((R + 1i*2*pi*f.*L)./(G + 1i*2*pi*f.*C));

% Plot results
loglog(f, 2*pi*f*sqrt(L*C));
xlabel('Frequency (Hz)');
ylabel('Phase Coefficient');
title('Phase Coefficient vs Freq');

hold on
loglog(f, beta);
grid on;
```

I get this plot;

[image]

I am confused as to why at higher frequencies the two lines don't merge like in the characteristic plot

Answer (score 0):

In place of "phase coefficient", plot "group speed" (which seems "weird" ... \$ vph = 3.71*10^8 m/s\$).
Plot is done from f=1 Hz (ffmin=0) to f=10^10 Hz (ffmax=10).

[image]